# Mobile site for TCS.SE (no colors on iPhone)

Tags: support, design

Have anyone checked if there is a mobile version of the site? I normally like to read questions from my iphone, and I notice the other day that the design changed (the mobile version). For instance, like a few days ago, the web page I used to see was exactly the same as the original web page. But now it changed, the design is totally different, with at least for me very ugly colors (or no colors, mostly grayscale).

Are the people at the stackexchange working in some special version for mobile devices? At least for iphone, having the original design works great.

Comment: It seems that they have changed the mobile version again, it looks much nicer now.

Comment: in iphone I used to see the "mobile" website like the "original" website. But now the new mobile version has no colors at all!

Comment: The colors are back on my phone (Android).

Comment: on my iphone I can still see only grayscale :-(

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, according to: [Mobile optimized version of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so/50689#50689)

See also the discussion at Math.SE: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1726/again-with-the-style-change

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer to your question but I think this is also useful.

I use an android smartphone and use the app [Droidstack](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.droidstack). You can use it for every SE site not only TCS.SE. Currently it doesn't support MathJax. So if you want to read the questions with math support you have to open it in your browser (there is a button in this app to do this).

Additionally it checks your reputation score if you want to and notifies any changes. It isn't a full client. You can't post any questions/answers/comments. But if you only wan't to read the questions/answers/comments this is a great app.

Do anybody use some other apps (iphone/ipad or android)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my experience: I have no problem browsing TCS SE on my Nokia 97 mini using Opera Mobile browser. Math support is perfect and renders correctly without any problems. I guess you may get the same experience if you use Opera Mobile browser on Android devices.